# GATLING Scala feeder into file

Tags: simulation, filewriter, scala-2.9, gatling

I am trying to feed the values of a feeder that supplies Id's into a .txt File. Is their any way to extract values directly from the feeder without having to extract the Id from each session?

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to rephrase/elaborate: your question doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

I not sure, what do you mean, but the way for extract values from feed you can use next :

val creditCard = "creditCard"

feed(tsv("CreditCard.txt").random)

Inside file "Credit.txt" you should have 1st line (column) name exactly as init value of variable -> "creditCard".

In this way you can use it like :  "${creditCard}" in you script.